# Uncaught ReferenceError: value is not defined on onChange method in React

Tags: reactjs

So I'm trying to pass an event in a component function with React, and I can't read the value from it.

Here is my Input component: (where I pass the function to it)

```
export default function Input({ placeholder, value, method, type }) {
  return (
    <input
      value={value}
      type={type}
      onChange={() => method()}
      placeholder={placeholder}
    />
  );
}
```

And this is how I pass the event:

```
<Input
  placeholder='20 Feb 2021'
  type='text'
  value={item.timeStarted}
  method={(e) => handleEdit(e, item.id, 'timeStarted')}
/>
```

And here is the function that I pass:

```
const handleEdit = (e, id, property) => {
    value = e.target.value;
    
    console.log(value, e) // both return undefined

    //logic here
  };
```

Comment: Try changing `onChange={() => method()}` to `onChange={method}`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava please justify your answer. It would be good for others to grab some concept

Comment: In the first case you call `method` without passing the event parameter to it `() => method()`; in the second case the parameter will be passed by default.. its the same as `(e) => method(e)`

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava I think it worked because of that change, idk